# I have two attr in appcompat_v7 and FloatingButtonAction

Tags: android, attr, android-appcompat, floating-action-button

My project contains these two libraries , but for some reason I get an error when I want to run it on my device :

The error is as follows:

```
workspace_desarrollo\Librerias\FloatingActionButton\res\values\attrs.xml:6: error: Attribute "color" has already been defined
```

Look at both libraries and found that both are defined . What I did was rename the FAB library and reads as follows:

```
<attr name="colortem" format="color"/>
```

Everything normal, but when you run the APP , the button shows me with white background. There are 3 buttons that use and puts three white background.

Previously I did not have this problem, but I had to change PC and when you import the new workspace projects started dating this error.

The appcompat_v7 this in : `target=android-21`

The FloatingActionButton this in : 
`target=android-19`
`android.library=true`
`android.library.reference.1=../nineoldandroids`

My project is in :
`target=android-21`
`android.library.reference.1=../../Librerias/FloatingActionButton`
`android.library.reference.2=../../Librerias/appcompat`
`android.library.reference.3=../../Librerias/google-play-services_lib`

I hope you can help me.

Thank You

PD : I'm thinking about starting to develop android studio , but I'm not entirely convinced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `colortem` attribute definition, the other one will be used. Otherwise you'd have to change all `R.attr.color` references inside FAB library to `R.attr.colortem` as well.